# get name for use in coxph in R language

Tags: r

I have a dataset with more than 100 metabolites and some covariates like Age, SEX, BMI. Now I want to test each single metabolites together with the covariates with coxph in a for loop.

My Problem is the formula and my laziness. How can I include the metabolite name in the formula? `get()` works but gives me only the expression `get(x)`. When I use only x I get error message `"Variable lengths differ"`.

here an example code:

```
x<-list(names(data))   

coxfit<-coxph(Surv(age, fup_alter, hyper)~ get(x) +Age + SEX + BMI, data=data,)
temp <- cox.zph(coxfit, transform = 'log') 
print(temp)
```

the result is:

```
                   rho    chisq      p                                        
get(x)         -0.06279 6.22e-01 0.4302                                        
SEX            -0.07272 7.59e-01 0.3838                                        
age            -0.02007 6.01e-02 0.8064                                        
BMI             0.01479 3.02e-02 0.8620
```

If I do this more than 100 times I can't distinguish between the `get(x)` in the result file.

Instead of `get(x)` I would like to have the names like "met1" or "met88".

Comment: `as.formula(paste("Surv(age, fup_alter, hyper)~", x, "+Age + SEX + BMI"))`

Answer (score 0):

I thought this might be cleaner, but it's about the same

```
#sample data
dd<-data.frame(
    a=1:10,
    b=rnorm(10),
    c=runif(10),
    y=rpois(10,5)
)

#get list of columns as proper "name" element
x <- lapply(names(dd)[-ncol(dd)], as.name)

#use bquote to inser names into formula
lapply(x, function(v) lm(bquote(y ~ .(v)), dd))
```

Here I use `lm` to create a run-able example. It should work the same for any model that uses a formula. Your call would look more like

```
coxph(bquote(Surv(age, fup_alter, hyper)~ .(x) +Age + SEX + BMI), data=data,)
```

Where `bquote` surrounds the entire formula and then use `.(x)` to insert the "name" elemennt into the formula. In my example `x` is a list so I need to iterate over it with `lapply`.